# Extract some part of text and format it desirably in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, text, text-mining

I want to extract some specific portion of information (text) from a bigger text, and export it based on my desired format. Below is an example

```
#Input
text={ Line 1: sergefdsgwerh Date is 10,29,2017
       Line 2aergsdfgsdfgasfdhgfasd
       Line 3: company Microsoft}

# Output
exported_text={ D 10 29 2017 C Microsoft}

x = []
with open("myfile.txt") as file:
    for l in file:
        x.append(l.strip())

X=[gives my lines as list item]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried any code? If not start trying out and if you get an error, then ask that here. And more over its a very simple thing, check how to read text file line by line and use simple logic to extract it. All the best. If you get any error, ask back

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I can only read and save each line in a list. I am new in this area, and would really appreciate if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think of three different ways to achieve what you want to do depending on what your input looks like and if you want to do it on multiple pieces of text or not.

For the following examples, let's say that your input is as such:

```
text = "Line 1: sergefdsgwerh Date is 10,29,2017\nLine 2aergsdfgsdfgasfdhgfasd\nLine 3: company Microsoft"
```

---

First, if you have only one piece of text or if your input is **always formatted in the exact same way**, you can retrieve the portion of information that you need quite easily using basic string manipulation in Python.

To write a working example, you can get what you want using:

```
date = text.replace("\n", " ").split(" ")[5].replace(",", " ")
company = text.replace("\n", " ").split(" ")[-1]
output_text = "D "+date+" C "+company

print(output_text)

# > D 10 29 2017 C Microsoft
```

Notice that we're using a bunch of functions here (there are many resources only to get to know these functions better and I suggest that you look into them if you're not familiar with these string manipulations):

- `text.replace("\n", " ")` replaces the skip line strings:`"\n"` strings with a space:`" "` in the entire string
- `text.split(" ")` splits the string into a list, with each split being done when a space:`" "` is encountered
- etc...

---

Second, **if your input is formatted in ways that vary by only a little**  between every input (for instance, the name of the company is always written just after the word "company"), one possible thing would be to use the `regex` library. Here's an instance if you want to isolate the company name. There are many ways to do what you want here using `regex` so I won't go into more details than this:

```
company = re.search(r'company (\S+)', text)

print(company.group(1))

# > Microsoft
```

---

Finally, **if your input is constantly changing**, what you want to do is much more complex and much more difficult to explain if you are new to Python. However, it can be worth noting that it can still be achieved using Named Entity Recognition which, for instance, can be done using the library SpaCy ([here](https://spacy.io)).

That said, given what your input seems to look like, using the standard models from this kind of such library wouldn't help you much (as they are trained on real instances of meaningful text), and you would need to train a model that would fit your specific use...